# Executing JNLP file throws a AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, jnlp, securitymanager

I am trying to execute [this](http://jfxtras.org/resources/java/Ensemble.jnlp) jnlp application.
However, I keep receiving this security exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:399)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:322)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2.init(FXApplet2.java:63)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXApplet2Adapter.init(FXApplet2Adapter.java:207)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.net.useSystemProxies" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:364)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:783)
    at ensemble.Ensemble2.<clinit>(Ensemble2.java:77)
    ... 10 more
```

I tried changing the security settings in the Java control panel (OSX 10.8.3), but they seem to be disabled and I cannot modify them (I do can check the "Enable Java content in the browser" option, but it is resetted when I click apply). This is shown in the following figure:

[image: Security tab in the Java Control Panel]

Is there another mechanism for bypassing the Java security manager and being able to execute a jnlp application ?

**UPDATE:**

After reinstalling Java I was finally able to change the security options in the Java Control panel (I did not do anything special, just reinstall it from scratch). Unfortunately, when I execute the [jnlp application](http://jfxtras.org/resources/java/Ensemble.jnlp) it dies silently without showing any errors. This problem could be related to the fact that I am using the jdk 1.8 (since the jnlp application requires javafx) and it is just a preview version (and OSX does not seem to like a lot Java these days...), it is my best guess but I cannot be completely sure.

Comment: check file with JaNeLA tool

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for this:

1. I have heard that Java 7 on Mac is still not stable.
2. By default JNLP files run in a "sandbox" to prevent malicious code from wreaking havoc on your system. This sandbox restricts access to the local filesystem and local network. I imagine that system properties are restricted too, and it looks like the app is trying to write to them. To allow unrestricted access, you need to sign the JAR file and configure the JNLP file with `<security><all-permissions/></security>`